# Angular js ng-show and ng-hide

Tags: angularjs

Here i have the code:

```
<ul ng-controller="Modalcontrol" class="card_ul">
                        <li ng-repeat="item in list">
                            {{item.name }}
                            <p>
                               <span class="yellow" align="left"  ng-repeat="labels in item.labels" ng-show="filter_card_id == labels.id"  >
                                   {{ labels.id }} 
                               </span> 
                               #{{ item.card_id }}
                            </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

In this ng-show="filter_card_id == labels.id" code worked properly but i want to apply this show and hide to this parent list. how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter in parent list like this:

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    this.list = [{
      id: 1,
      labels: [{
        id: 11
      }, {
        id: 12
      }]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      labels: [{
        id: 21
      }, {
        id: 22
      }]
    }, {
      id: 3,
      labels: [{
        id: 31
      }, {
        id: 32
      }]
    }];
    this.filter = {
      id: undefined
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <label>
      Filter
      <input type="number" ng-model="vm.filter.id" />
    </label>
    <ul ng-repeat="item in vm.list|filter:{labels:{id:vm.filter.id?vm.filter.id:undefined}}:true">
      <li>{{item.id}}
        <ul ng-repeat="label in item.labels|filter:{id:vm.filter.id?vm.filter.id:undefined}:true">
          <li>{{label.id}}</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/vup8jxqf/).

Comment: Thanks Stepen. This is one is working. But When i will give the input as an array. How it is?

Comment: I have one more doubt. How ti display all data by default. when i click the input value, then only filter apply. How?

Comment: @SARAN Filter by array is another issue. I'm updated jsfiddle for display all data by default.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$parent`

```
ng-show="filter_card_id == $parent.labels.id"
```

Comment: @SARAN you're in a foreach loop, so to access the properties of the parent of the itteration you use `$parent`

Comment: Your parent list should have $parent.labels